# Functional dependency help and decomposition

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Need some help with the following FDS to minimalise and to decompose it to BCNF or normal form

```
docID -> docname

patID -> patname, patDOB

patId, appdate, apptime -> docID, roomNo

appdate, docID -> roomNo

patID, appdate -> appTime, roomNo, docID
```

Comment: Sorry, what are FDS and BCNF stand for?

Comment: What about `patId` or `appdate` or `roomNo`?